# Customize class and html display with WTforms

Tags: flask, wtforms

i m trying to finetune some of the forms i use on a dashboard and migrating all of them to WTforms but i'm struggling to keep the format in one of them.
 One of the forms i want to migrate is actually pre-populated, it's nor really a form, more like a table with user info on it, but to simplify i would like to use WTforms to display it like the real forms that are on the same page (maybe it's not a good idea to use WTform for this kind of table?).
 Anyway in the non WTform version each line is coded as

```
<li>
  <span class="key"><i class="icol-group"></i> Number of followers </span>
<span class="val"><span class="text-nowrap">{{user.nb_followers}}</span></span>
</li>
```

i created a form in my forms.py with the relevant fields:

```
 class Summary(Form):
 Nb_followers = TextField("Number of followers")
```

and updated the html to include the form

```
   <li>
      <span class="key">
       <i class="icol-group"></i>
       {{ S_form.Nb_followers.label(class_="key") }}
      </span>
      <span class="val">
       {{ S_form.Nb_followers(class_="text-nowrap") }}
       </span>
   </li>
```

On the Label side it's almost ok (font and format is correct) except that the icon in the

```
<i class="icol-group"></i>
```

and the label name are not in a single line, there is a break after the icon. 
On the input side it's really ugly, the field is by default considered as a form input (this is what i see in the firebug console)

```
<input id="Nb_followers" class="val" type="text" value="" name="Nb_followers">
```

and it imports a whole set of css rules i have for forms inputs.. ( wish i could put screenshots to explain better, but not enough reputation :( )

is there a way i can, 1/ properly input an icon in my label 2/ overwrite the class to deactivate the input type

or more general advice on managing class & display in wtforms

thx a lot

Comment: I don't see any benefit in using WTForms for just displaying data. It's primarily used for input validation & CSRF protection on forms and you need none in this case.

Comment: I guess, i m starting to think it's not a good idea too. Just it seemed easier to use only forms on the page to gather and display the data but if there are too many display limitations i will give itup..